# Scrollbar or ScrollViewer when windows sizes reduces

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, scrollview

I want to know if there is a way to not size the width and height of a grid I have but when I reduce the size of a window if my graph becomes a certain width/height then the corresponding scrollviewer appear, is it possible to do in XAML or do I need to do this in code behind? So I want my Controls to have widths and if the window gets below them then I want to be able to enable the scroll viewers that I have

**XAML**

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="MyScrollViewer" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <Grid Background="White" x:Name="OuterGrid">

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="70"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

<Grid Background="White" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="UIWindow" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1.2*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1.2*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1.5*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1.5*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

<TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="25,3,0,2" Height="17" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="70" Text="Facies" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" FontFamily="{StaticResource FontFamily}"/>
            <Path Data="M2.4,62 L103.4,62" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="1" Margin="5,20,0,0" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="#A8A8A8" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"/>
            <Controls:FaciesControl x:Name="FaciesFilter" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,25,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="300" Width="195" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="3"/>

            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Text="Zone Legend:" Width="150" Height="15" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10" FontFamily="{StaticResource FontFamily}"/>
            <Path Data="M2.4,62 L103.4,62" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="1" Margin="5,27,0,0" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="#A8A8A8" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2"/>
            <Controls:LegendControl x:Name="LegendFilter" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="450" Margin="5,50,0,0" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="224" Grid.RowSpan="4"/>

            <TextBlock Text="Sequence Stratigraphy" FontFamily="{StaticResource FontFamily}" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,5,0,0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"/>
            <Path Data="M2.4,62 L103.4,62" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="1" Margin="5,20,0,0" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="#A8A8A8" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="355" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"/>
            <Stratigraphy:StratiGraphControl x:Name="stratiGraphControl" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="4" Margin="0,40,40,10"/>
```

Comment: You have properties for `FrameworkElement` like `MaxWidth` `MaxHeight` [FrameworkElement.MaxWidth](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.maxwidth%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Yeah but if I have the application on a bigger screen then if it goes on a bigger screen it would look small when the screen is maximised, when it's maximised the Controls are perfect it's just when I reduce the size of the Window

Comment: So I see your controls are not responsive and they have their values set, you just want to show/hide the `ScrollViewer` when the window size get's smaller? If that's right two options come to mind 1. Bind to your main container's actual width and use converter to set the visibility of your scrollviewer to the appropriate value. 2. Use `SizeChanged` event of the window and in your code behind set the appropriate visibility to the `ScrollViewer` . Second option is easier and I'm not sure if first one will work (I think i had some issues with `ActualWidth` not firing it's changed handler)

Comment: OK thanks I shall give the second option a try, just with u being a lot more confident with that than the first one

Comment: Can you give me an example as to how to do the second option in code behind please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you requested in the comments an example for the second approach. It's only doing the scrollviewer logic so I do not know if this is enough in your case but that is what you ask for so here it is:

This code will hide/show vertical/horizontal scrollbar if window size is below/above given values

**XAML** - put this in your window

```
SizeChanged="Window_SizeChanged"
```

**Code Behind**

```
private void Window_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.NewSize.Width <= 500)
    {
        MyScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Visible;
    }
    else
    {
        MyScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Disabled;
    }
    if (e.NewSize.Height <= 500)
    {
        MyScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Visible;
    }
    else
    {
        MyScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Disabled;
    }
}
```

Comment: No problem. By the way maybe You'll have to add the same logic on first start, meaning if resize doesn't fire and user starts the app in small screen it's not going to show scrollbars until user resizes right now.